# Creación de usuarios a través de SDK HIKVISION ISAPI- SERVICIO C#

Tags: c#, .net, servicio

tengo un problema en el momento que intento replicar o crear usuarios automáticamente a través de un servicio c# en donde recorre cada uno de los relojes biometricos que tengo disponibles y se loguea automaticamente, eso me funciona bien, sin problemas. Ya que ya tengo el mismo proceso para replicar imagenes tomadas en cada uno de los relojes, utilizando el SDK de Hikvision.

El SDK para crear un usuario necesita de los campos, codigoEmpleado, nombre y RigthPlan, pero realmente el ultimo campo es indiferente sobre que valor enviarle, ya que en lo personal no lo estoy ocupando para algo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He creado una funcion para obtener el codigo del empleado y de momento el nombre pasarle un "user" ahora el tercer campo como es indiferente no se si eso me este dando problema, ya que en la ruta de ISAPI le estoy mandando un 1 directamente.

```
 private List<string> ObtenerCodigoEmpleadoReplicar()
 {

     List<string> codigosEmpleado = new List<string>();

     try
     {
         //cadena de conn
         string Servidor = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Servidor"].ToString();
         string BaseDatos = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseDatos"].ToString();
         string Usuario_Login_DB = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Usuario_Login_DB"].ToString();
         string Password_DB = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password_DB"].ToString();

         string connectionString = ObtenerConnectionStringDesdeArchivo(Servidor, BaseDatos, Usuario_Login_DB, Password_DB);

         using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
         {
             connection.Open();

             string qry = "SELECT CodigoEmpleado FROM REP_ImagenEmpleadoRondaSeg";

             using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qry, connection))
             {
                 using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                 {
                     while (reader.Read())
                     {
                         string codigo = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("CodigoEmpleado"));
                         codigosEmpleado.Add(codigo);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {


         EventLog.WriteEntry("Error al obtener el codigo de empleado: " + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
     }
     return codigosEmpleado;

 }
```

Este es mi evento que se encarga de realizar la replicacion de imagenes y ahora que deseo la de usuarios (donde empieza el foreach)

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //timer1.Stop();

    try
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Inicio de proceso de Actualizacion de Biometros", EventLogEntryType.Information);

        //Obtener el listado de los dispositivos desde la DB
        var ListaDispositivos = GetDeviceList();
        // Obtener la lista de códigos de empleado desde la base de datos
        List<string> codigosEmpleado = ObtenerCodigoEmpleadoReplicar();


        //Iteramos sobre cada uno de los relojes disponibles
        for (int dispositivoBiometrico = 0; dispositivoBiometrico < ListaDispositivos.Count; dispositivoBiometrico++)
        {
            **// Iterar sobre cada código de empleado y crear usuarios en el reloj
            foreach (string codigoEmpleado in codigosEmpleado)
            {
                crearUsuarioEnReloj(ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].DireccionIP, ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].Puerto.ToString(),
                    ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].Usuario, ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].Clave, codigoEmpleado, "NombreGeneral");
            }**

            //Actualizar la imagen de cada uno de los empleados a cada dispositivo 
            List<string> file_list = new List<string>();
            //hacemos uso de la funcion "searchDirectory, para hacer referencia la ruta completa
            SearchDirectory(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirectorioPicture"].ToString(), file_list);


            //iteramos sobre la lista de dispositivos pasandole cada una de las imagenes disponibles
            for (int imagenLocal = 0; imagenLocal < file_list.Count; imagenLocal++)
            {
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(file_list[imagenLocal]);
                Actualizar_ImagenesDispositivos(ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].DireccionIP, ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].Puerto.ToString(),
                    ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].Usuario, ListaDispositivos[dispositivoBiometrico].Clave, file.Name.Replace(".jpg", ""), file_list[imagenLocal]);
            }
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Fin de proceso de Actualizacion de Biometros", EventLogEntryType.Information);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }
    // timer1.Start();
    EventLog.WriteEntry("Se actualizo correctamente la replicacion de imagenes", EventLogEntryType.Information);
}
```

Esta es mi funcion que creaElUsuario

```
 private void crearUsuarioEnReloj(string pIPDispositivo, string pPuertoDispositivo, string pUsuarioDispositivo, string pContraseñaDispositivo, string pCodigoEmpleado, string pNombreEmpleado)
 {
     try
     {
         string szUrl = "/ISAPI/AccessControl/UserInfo/SetUp?format=json";
         string szRequest = "{\"UserInfo\":{\"employeeNo\":\"" + pCodigoEmpleado +
             "\",\"name\":\"" + pNombreEmpleado +
             "\",\"userType\":\"normal\",\"Valid\":{\"enable\":true,\"beginTime\":\"2017-08-01T17:30:08\",\"endTime\":\"2020-08-01T17:30:08\"},\"doorRight\": \"1\",\"RightPlan\":[{\"doorNo\":1,\"planTemplateNo\":\"" + "1" + "\"}]}}";
         string szMethod = "PUT";

         string szResponse = ActionISAPI(pIPDispositivo, pPuertoDispositivo, pUsuarioDispositivo, pContraseñaDispositivo, szUrl, szRequest, szMethod);

         if (szResponse != string.Empty)
         {
             ResponseStatus rs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseStatus>(szResponse);
             if (1 == rs.statusCode)
             {
                 EventLog.WriteEntry("Set UserInfo Succ!");
             }
             else
             {
                 EventLog.WriteEntry("No se pudo crear el usuario!", EventLogEntryType.Error);
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         EventLog.WriteEntry("Error en la replicacion de usuario: " + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Information);
     }
 }
```

Esta es mi funcion ISAPI

```
private string ActionISAPI(string IP, string Puerto, string strUsername, string strPassword, string szUrl, string szRequest, string szMethod)
 {
     string szResponse = string.Empty;


     if (!szUrl.Substring(0, 4).Equals("http"))
     {
         szUrl = "http://" + IP + ":" + Puerto + szUrl;
     }
     HttpClient clHttpClient = new HttpClient();
     byte[] byResponse = { 0 };
     int iRet = 0;
     string szContentType = string.Empty;

     switch (szMethod)
     {
         case "GET":
             iRet = clHttpClient.HttpRequest(strUsername, strPassword, szUrl, szMethod, ref byResponse, ref szContentType);
             break;
         case "PUT":
             iRet = clHttpClient.HttpPut(strUsername, strPassword, szUrl, szMethod, szRequest, ref szResponse);
             break;
         case "POST":
             iRet = clHttpClient.HttpPut(strUsername, strPassword, szUrl, szMethod, szRequest, ref szResponse);
             break;
         default:
             break;
     }

     if (iRet == (int)HttpClient.HttpStatus.Http200)
     {
         if ((!szMethod.Equals("GET")) || (szContentType.IndexOf("application/xml") != -1))
         {
             if (szResponse != string.Empty)
             {
                 return szResponse;
             }

             if (szMethod.Equals("GET"))
             {
                 szResponse = Encoding.Default.GetString(byResponse);
                 return szResponse;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             if (byResponse.Length != 0)
             {
                 szResponse = Encoding.Default.GetString(byResponse);
                 return szResponse;
             }
         }
     }
     else if (iRet == (int)HttpClient.HttpStatus.HttpOther)
     {
         string szCode = string.Empty;
         string szError = string.Empty;
         clHttpClient.ParserResponseStatus(szResponse, ref szCode, ref szError);
         MessageBox.Show("Request failed! Error code:" + szCode + " Describe:" + szError + "\r\n");
     }
     else if (iRet == (int)HttpClient.HttpStatus.HttpTimeOut)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(szMethod + " " + szUrl + "error!Time out");
     }
     return szResponse;
 }
```

Los errores son los siguientes

string szResponse = ActionISAPI(pIPDispositivo, pPuertoDispositivo, pUsuarioDispositivo, pContraseñaDispositivo, szUrl, szRequest, szMethod);

**ERROR: PUT https://10.10.9.131:8000/ISAPI/AccessControl/UserInfo/SetUp?format=jsonerror!time Out**

En la linea

**ResponseStatus rs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(szResponse);**

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: R. Path '', line 0, position 0.'Esta excepción se generó originalmente en esta pila de llamadas:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, bool)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, System.Type, bool)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, System.Type)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string, System.Type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)
ServiceTest.Form1.crearUsuarioEnReloj(string, string, string, string, string, string) en Form1.cs